# Arranging people in a line without specific people at either end

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can ten people be arranged in a line if neither of two particular people can sit on either end of the row?

What i thought was find how many ways one particular person must sit at either end then multiply that value by 2 then subtract it from how many ways ten people can be arranged without restriction

Comment: I've noticed that for the past hour or so, you've been posting questions all on elementary combinatorics, with very similar names, showing only your questions, without demonstrating any attempt at finding an answer. Maybe you should put in a little more effort into finding an answer yourself, or at least showing where you have trouble, before posting a question. Also, you should give your questions more specific names to distinguish them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if neither of two particular people can sit on either end of the row"? Can I assume that then you have 8 choices in the front end then 7 choices in the back end?

Comment: Does 'two particular people sitting on either end' mean configurations like AxxxxB and BxxxxA only, or also ABxxxx, BAxxxx, xxxxAB and xxxxBA?

Comment: I'm very new to the website. It may be elementary but I find them hard. The problem with these types of questions is that you cant show someone how you've tried it. You either get it or you don't.

Comment: Hint:  choose a person for the left, choose a person for the right, then permute the remainder.

Comment: That is incorrect. You can definitely show us, at the very least, how you are thinking about solving the question.

Comment: What i thought was find how many ways one particular person must sit at either end then multiply that value by 2 then subtract it from how many ten people can be arranged without restriction

Comment: Not to mention that none of the questions you've asked are particularly harder than the others. If you ask one question, receive an answer, and soon after ask another question of the same type, no more difficult than the last, without making any improvement in providing some work, it shows that you haven't adequately mulled over the answers already given to you.

Comment: Alright, that's something. The problem with that approach is double counting: the case where person $A$ is sitting on one end includes some arrangements where person $B$ is on the other end, which is counted when you count how many ways person $B$ is on one end. Try using lulu's hint.

Comment: As a suggestion for working on problems like these:  if you think you have a good method, try it with a smaller collection.  In this case, say, suppose you had four people, $A,B,C,D$ and that neither $A$ nor $B$ can be on an end.  Now, it is easy to simply list all the cases so you can test your method out.  Just asking other people to do it for you is a terrible way to learn anything.

Comment: All right, since you are new to the site, edit your question with your last comment where you outlined your thought process :). That way a potential responder doesn't have to scroll through the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In how many ways can ten people be arranged in a line if neither of two particular people can sit on either end of the row?

Without any restrictions, $10!$ ways you can arrange them

$9!\times 2 $ ways where first person is at any end
$9!\times 2 $ ways where second person is at any end

$8!\times 2 $ ways where both persons are at end

Then use inclusion-exclusion for answer 
$10! - (9!\times 2 + 9!\times 2) + 8!\times 2 $

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I had mistaken the question for the number of permutations when neither are sitting together at either ends.

Answer (score 4):

You have $8$ choices for the person sitting on one end (because there are only $8$ people that can be on either end), you have $7$ choices for the person sitting on the other end (because you already put a person on the end and you still can't put two people on the end), and then you have $8!$ for the rest of the people. Your total is therefore $8*7*8!$.